# php custom string to array with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use regex in PHP to parse a string and make an array. Here is my attempt:

```
function parseItemName($itemname) {
    // Given item name like "2 of #222001." or "3 of #222001; 5 of #222002."
    // Return array like (222001 => 2) or (222001 => 3, 222002 => 5)
    preg_match('/([0-9]?) of #([0-9]?)(.|;\s)/', $itemname, $matches);
    return $matches;
}
```

Calling the function with

```
print_r(parseItemName("3 of #222001; 5 of #222002."));
```

returns

```
Array ( [0] => 3 of #22 [1] => 3 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 )
```

Does anyone know how to make this work? I assume that preg_match() is not the best way to do this, but I'm not sure what else to try. I appreciate any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: you can't match things into the array key with preg_match.

Comment: have you tried `preg_match_all()` rather than just `preg_match()` ... should give you a multidimensional array which might be a little closer to what you're after?

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. You can rename the key for every match with (?P<myKey>\d+). But you cannot use dynamic text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the adjustment to your regex pattern, you want to be using `preg_match_all` with the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag set to make things simpler.

This will return a `$matches` array arranged like so:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '3 of #222001' (length=12)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string '222001' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '5 of #222002' (length=12)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => string '222002' (length=6)
```

The below example function now loops through all of the matches, and constructs a new array, using the second match as the key, and the first match as the value.

```
function parseItemName($itemname) {
    // Given item name like "2 of #222001." or "3 of #222001; 5 of #222002."
    // Return array like (222001 => 2) or (222001 => 3, 222002 => 5)
    preg_match_all('/(\d+)\sof\s#(\d+)/', $itemname, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $newArray = array();

    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $newArray[$match[2]] = intval($match[1]);
    }

    return $newArray;
}

var_dump(parseItemName("3 of #222001; 5 of #222002."));
```

The output that is dumped will look like this:

```
array
  222001 => int 3
  222002 => int 5
```

Comment: @Alex, I just noticed something. In your comment you have "2 of #222001. or 3 of #222001". If the 222001 occurs more than once, the array value will be overwritten, since 222001 is being used as a key. You can turn it into a nested array structure inside the loop to get around this (`$newArray[$match[2]][] = intval($match[1]);` - note the extra `[]` before the `=`)

Comment: Leigh - Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

```
([0-9]?)
      ^--- "0 or 1 of ...
```

What you want is `+` instead, which is "1 or more", and would capture all of the digits, not just the first one.

Comment: It is now returning `Array ( [0] => 3 of #222001; [1] => 3 [2] => 222001 [3] => ; )`... Any ideas on how to make the array look like `(222001 => 3, 222002 => 5)`?

Comment: That's normal. preg_match returns element 0 as the whole string that matched, element #1 the first capture group, element #2 the 2nd capture group, etc... You'll have to post-process it into that format yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
/(\d*?)\sof\s#(\d*)\b/
```

EDIT: Remove the lazy match as commented in this post.

Comment: Are you sure you want a lazy match on those digits? Will that not only match 1 if it's `143 of #222001` ?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! How do you think I should use the new regex? I tried updating the fourth line above with `preg_match('/(\d*?)\sof\s#(\d*?)\b/', $itemname, $matches);` but now the return is `Array ( [0] => 3 of # [1] => 3 [2] => )`....

Comment: @WouterJ - except that link doesn't point to the RegExp you've written, you've dropped the lazy match on the second digit in that linked version, so it works, `/(\d*?)\sof\s#(\d*)\b/` rather than `/(\d*?)\sof\s#(\d*?)\b/` - though tbh just `/(\d*)\sof\s#(\d*)\b/` should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseItemName( $itemname ) {

  preg_match_all( '/([0-9]+) of #([0-9]+)/', $itemname, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );

  $items = array();

  foreach ( $matches as $match ) {

    $items[ $match[2] ] = $match[1];

  }
  // foreach


  return $items;

}
// parseItemName
```

Comment: I read them before writing my own.  I'm not going to write one then check for more recent ones.